# Find differences between rows with duplicate(s) in one field

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I am about to remove duplicates from my database using

```
delete from table 
  where id not in (
    select min(id) 
      from table 
      group by foreign_key);
```

However, I would like to do so with the following conditions:

- if any of the duplicate rows have a value in `fieldA` or `fieldB`

  - if any of the duplicates have a value for `fieldA` or `fieldB`, but there is only one unique value in each field, keep that value
  - if there is more than one unique value in each row, report this information along with the `id` and `foreign_key` so that the value can be fixed manually.

By default, `fieldA` and `fieldB` are `NULL`, but data have been entered in these fields in some cases.

Here is some sample data:

```
| id | foreign_key | fieldA | fieldB |
|----+-------------+--------+--------|
|  1 |           1 | NULL   | NULL   |
|  2 |           1 | A1     | B1     |
|  3 |           1 | NULL   | NULL   |
|  4 |           2 | A2     | B2     |
|  5 |           2 | A3     | B2     |
|  6 |           3 | NULL   | NULL   |
|  7 |           4 | A4     | B4     |
|  8 |           5 | A5     | NULL   |
|  9 |           5 | NULL   | B5     |
| 10 |           6 | A6     | B6     |
| 11 |           6 | A7     | B6     |
| 12 |           7 | NULL   | B7     |
| 13 |           7 | NULL   | B7     |
```

What I want to keep is:

```
| id | foreign_key | fieldA | fieldB |
|----+-------------+--------+--------|
|  2 |           1 | A1     | B1     |
|  4 |           2 | NULL   | B2     |
|  6 |           3 | NULL   | NULL   |
|  7 |           4 | A4     | B4     |
|  8 |           5 | A5     | B5     |
| 10 |           6 | NULL   | B6     |
| 12 |           7 | NULL   | B7     |
```

And I would like this information to be returned:

```
foreign_key 2 has two distinct values of fieldA: A2 and A3
```

Comment: Would you provide sample data for the table and what should be removed?

Comment: @outis I have included sample data. for it is not necessary that the row with `id=4` be returned, only that `foreign_key=2` is identified as having > 1 result for `fieldA`.

Comment: The sample doesn't make sense. There's only one row with foreign_key=2, and no fieldA stores 'A2' or 'A3'.

Comment: @outis sorry, I forgot to paste one the starting table

Comment: Do you need to have id=2 for the row with fieldA='A1' and fieldB='B1', or could it have the ID of any row where foreign_key=1?

Comment: @outis it could have the id of any row where foreign key = 1

Comment: I've added a few more test rows. Did I assume correctly what data you want to keep?

Comment: @David: am I on the right track with the below queries?

Comment: @outis you pretty much answered my question - I can fit this into an update/delete statement, but first I'll have to change all of the records where t1.id is a foreign key (e.g. t2.t1_id etc...). But that should be easy too. The group concat was a nice feature. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got to run of right now, but here's a query to start with:

```
SELECT id, foreign_key, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT fieldA) as A, count(DISTINCT fieldA) as `#A`,
    group_concat(DISTINCT fieldB) as B, count(DISTINCT fieldB) as `#B`
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY foreign_key
;
```

On the test data, this returns:

> ```
> | id | foreign_key | A     | #A | B    | #B |
> +----+-------------+-------+----+------+----+
> |  1 |           1 | A1    |  1 | B1   |  1 |
> |  4 |           2 | A2,A3 |  2 | B2   |  1 |
> |  6 |           3 | NULL  |  0 | NULL |  0 |
> |  7 |           4 | A4    |  1 | B4   |  1 |
> |  8 |           5 | A5    |  1 | B5   |  1 |
> | 10 |           6 | A6,A7 |  2 | B6   |  1 |
> | 12 |           7 | NULL  |  0 | B7   |  1 |
> ```

Query for rows to keep:

```
SELECT id, foreign_key, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT fieldA) as A, count(DISTINCT fieldA) as `#A`, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT fieldB) as B, count(DISTINCT fieldB) as `#B`
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY foreign_key
  HAVING `#A` < 2 AND `#B` < 2
;
```

Query for rows that need operator intervention:

```
SELECT id, foreign_key, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT fieldA) as A, count(DISTINCT fieldA) as `#A`, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT fieldB) as B, count(DISTINCT fieldB) as `#B`
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY foreign_key
  HAVING `#A` >= 2 OR `#B` >= 2
;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` may not be suitable, depending on the format of data stored in the columns. In combination with #A and #B, however, you could detect when it's not suitable, so it shouldn't be a big problem. It may also have too big a performance impact, but I can't think of another aggregate function that could be used in the same way (a `GROUP_COALESCE` would be nice).